# Microsoft Graph API - How to find out which files changed in personal one drive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to learn how to use MS Graph Notifications API. Specifically, what I'm trying to do is subscribe to all changes that happen in my "Microsoft Teams Chat Files" folder in OneDrive.
This subscription works in the sense that it tells me when something has happened:

```
{
   "changeType": "updated",
   "notificationUrl": "{{my-endpoint}}",
   "resource": "users/{{my-id}}/drive/root",
   "expirationDateTime":"2021-03-13T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
}
```

And this is the response data I get back:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "subscriptionId": "{{somevalue}}",
      "clientState": "secretClientValue",
      "resource": "users/{{my-id}}/drive/root",
      "tenantId": "{{tenantID}}",
      "resourceData": null,
      "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2021-03-13T10:23:45.9356913-08:00",
      "changeType": "updated"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the resourceData is null.  I was under the impression that it would at least return a file ID so I can turn around and requery for details, but it doesn't.

Per their documentation it seems that you can only request resource data (includeResourceData: true) for specific types of objects/resources, and OneDrive is not one of them.  However, I'm curious to know if there's another way to go about this?

I'm presently looking into how delta queries / notifications work to see if that might give me what I need.

Thanks in advance for any tips / help

Answer (score 0):

I think that `includeResourceData` property should be set to true to explicitly request resource data.

But according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data) it seems that drive item resource is not [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data#supported-resources).

Comment: You can't create a subscription for OneDrive notifications with iincludeResourceData.  It returns a 500.  and +1 to the documentation saying that you cannot request resource Data for these types of changes.  But I'm wondering if there's another way to find out what changed under the hood.